# How to recursively delete directories skipping some directories/files from command line in windows?

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, window

Suppose I have a complex path of directories:

```
<ROOT>
  folder1
  folder2
    sub1
    sub2
  folder3
    sub1
    sub2
    ...
```

and suppose in some folders there are files named "skip.me"

How can I delete all content in all "folderX" directories skipping the "skip.me" files (and their containing folder)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using the powershell command "rm":

```
rm "folder*\*" -recurse -force -exclude "skip.me"
```